# How do I Random all the items in the listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, random, listbox, windows-store-apps

I don't want to random number, I want to random all the items in the listbox in C# XAML Windows Store App??

Anyone have code for that or have any idea how to do that?

I have this code of listbox

```
<ListBox Name="Playlist" Background="White" DoubleTapped="Playlist_DoubleTapped" KeyUp="Playlist_KeyUp"
     Foreground="Black" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Playlist_SelectionChanged"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
     Grid.Column="0" Margin="28,82,1067,32">
```

@Baldrick this is how i am adding songs/videos to the playlist listbox

```
public async void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
    filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Play";
    foreach (string fileExtension in supportedAudioFormats)
    {
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileExtension);
    }
    foreach (string fileExtension in supportedVideoFormats)
    {
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileExtension);
    }

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> selectedFiles = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
    if (selectedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (StorageFile file in selectedFiles)
        {
            Playlist.Items.Add(file);
        }
        systemMediaControls.IsEnabled = true;

        mediaSource.AutoPlay = true;
        await SetNewMediaItem(0);   // Start with first file in the list of picked files.
        StorageFile files = Playlist.SelectedItem as StorageFile;
        Thumbnail(files);
    }
}
```

Comment: what function or event will be triggering the randomization of the listbox items?

Comment: Click="Button_Click" will be the button which will randomize all the items in the listbox

Comment: You'd be better off binding the `ItemsSource` property to a backing list (such as an ObservableCollection) in your viewmodel, then using a Fischer-Yates shuffle on the bound list.  This is cleaner and will save you having to mess around with the items in the ListBox.

Comment: Can you post the function that is triggered by the `Button_Click` event?

Comment: @Nathan well i am currently working of the music player app..i can random the selected index..but i want to random the whole list..please tell me how to do that

public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          Rand();   
        }

public void Rand()
        {
           Playlist.SelectedIndex = rnd.Next(Playlist.Items.Count - 1);
        }

Comment: @Baldrick i am very new to win store apps..i did.nt understand what you said..can you please tell me in other simple words

Comment: In that case you might be better off sorting the actual items - it will fit better with your current design that probably doesn't use any databindings. Can you post the code where you add the items to the `ListBox`? Then I'll have a better idea how your app is designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="Playlist" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlaylistItems}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="Shuffle" Content="Shuffle" Click="Shuffle_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that there is `PlaylistItems` binded to `ListBox`. It would be the best to manipulate the collection of items, which is binded to `ListBox`, instead of manipulating `ListBox` itself.

C# code:

First you should define that `PlaylistItems` collection.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> PlaylistItems
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And to make it possible to bind it to the `ListBox`, it is necessary to set the `DataContext` of your control (window or whatever).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;  // <--
}
```

Now let's initialize `PlaylistItems` collection and add few items.

```
public void InitializeItems(int count)
{
    var items = new List<string>(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        items.Add("Item " + i);

    PlaylistItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(items);
}
```

You can call this method in the constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializePlaylist(10); // <--
}
```

And finally shuffle functionality.

```
public IEnumerable<string> ShuffleItems(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    return items.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next()).ToList();
}
```

Use it in your button handler to repopulate `PlaylistItems` with randomized items.

```
private void Shuffle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var shuffledItems = ShuffleItems(PlaylistItems);

    PlaylistItems.Clear();

    foreach (var item in shuffledItems)
        PlaylistItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: wow..now the list is shuffling..i was not able to do this little small thing since last 2 days..thank you
A Very BIG THANK YOU @Anton Kedrov
thanks for helping me :)

Comment: okay so now i can shuffle the list but now how to shuffle the storage file list(for example songs list)???

Comment: This code works for any type of items. Just replace `ObservableCollection<string> PlaylistItems` with `ObservableCollection<StorageFile> PlaylistItems`, `public IEnumerable<string> ShuffleItems(IEnumerable<string> items)` with `public IEnumerable<StorageFile> ShuffleItems(IEnumerable<StorageFile> items)`, etc.

Comment: And you will need to modify your `ListBox` accordingly. You will need to add the `ItemTemplate`. For example: `<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="Playlist" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlaylistItems}"><ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SOME_TEXT_PROPERTY_OF_StorageFile}"/></DataTemplate></ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox>`

Comment: awesome..everything works like a charm when people like u help us beginners to learn..thank you :)

just 1 silly thing to ask what to right here "SOME_TEXT_PROPERTY_OF_StorageFile"

Comment: If you are binding `StorageFile` items, then it will be one of the properties of the `StorageFile`. Like `Name`, `Path` or `DisplayName`.